# how can I find intro template for a web sub pages

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have three subdomain of company.

- `building.mydomain.com`
- `shipping.mydomain.com`
- `production.mydomain.com`

I have created these web sites with wordpress. But I want a template for main domain `www.mydomain.com`

This template should be an intro page. Users will select a sub page.

But I could not find an intro template HTML + CSS

Can you offer?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use Bootstrap. Here you can find some free bootstrap templates to get you started: [bootstrapzero](http://bootstrapzero.com)
and [startbootstrap](http://startbootstrap.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[YellowBird](http://themes.persitheme.com/yellowbird/color/) Here you have a simple template with a slideshow with 3 images. ([Here's to buy](http://themeforest.net/item/yellow-bird-multipurpose-onepage-theme/7921495?WT.oss_phrase=wordpress%20select%20web&WT.oss_rank=20&WT.z_author=PersianArt&WT.ac=search_thumb)).

It's just an example, it would be better if you tell us what is the topic of the webs or if you would pay for a template. If you are considerating to pay for a template check [ThemeForest WordPress Category](http://themeforest.net/category/wordpress).

Lastly, consider "landing page" as key words when searching.